# How to dynamically hide/remove some menus from navigation?

Tags: plugins, menu, navigation

I'm working on a wordpress plugin which inserts some pages using `wp_insert_post()` on activation. These pages are then used for different purposes (user account dashboard, edit account info, change password, login, logout, etc...).

Issue is all these pages get some menus which are displayed to all frontend users which is not correct because a non logged-in user for example should not see logout menu or any menu to a private page until authenticated. Now, I'm stucked at how to do just that. Any idea ?

I stress that the plugin login process is seperated from WP login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress **can not assign** restrictions and roles to specific pages, posts or terms by default.

You could create *two* separated menues and add a custom logic to your template.

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    wp_nav_menu('foo');
}
else
{
    wp_nav_menu('bar');
}
```

Comment: as I said it's a plugin not a theme!